# Display "guest" on webpage if User is not logged in

Tags: java, oracle, jsp, jdbc

I have the working Java code here to display a user's username upon login:

```
<%= "Welcome " + session.getAttribute("username")%>
```

If a user is not logged in and at my index.jsp page, it will display "Welcome null". 
However, I want to display "Welcome Guest" instead.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Write if/else. If getAttribute("username") null or empty, just print Guest.

Comment: Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3177733/139010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with [JSTL](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_standard_tag_library.htm):

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

Welcome, <c:out value="${sessionScope.username}" default="guest" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `JSTL` tag libraries. JSP scriplets are deprecated almost a decade back.

This is how you do it using JSTL:

```xml
Welcome, <c:out value = "${sessionScope.username == null ? 'Guest' : sessionScope.username}" />
```

**See also:**

- Our [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) tag Wiki.
- [How to avoid Java code in JSP files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3177733/1679863)

Comment: @user2297666. I've used the conditional operator inside the EL expression. You can learn more about JSTL, in the links attached.

Comment: @user2297666. What are you getting?

Comment: @user2297666. Ah! One little mistake I did. You can try it now.

Comment: Just a Welcome : and that is all

Comment: @user2297666. It should work now. I forgot the quotes around the "Guest".